# C Programming Passing Character Function

Tags: c, function, if-statement

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define SIZE 200

 void check(char str[]);

 void check(char str[]){
        /* checking if the characters entered are digits */
        int i;
        int j=0;
        char tel[10];

        for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){
                tel[j++] = str[i];
            }
        }
        tel[j] = '\0';

    /* checking if length of zip code  is less than 5 digits */
    if(strlen(tel) < 5)
            printf("Not enough digits on input!");


    /* if length of zip code is 5 digits */
    else if (strlen(tel) == 5){
        printf("\nProgram Output: ");
        printf("(");

        /* formating zip code with parenthesis around zip */
        for(i = 0; tel[i] != '\0' && i < 5; i++){
            printf("%c", tel[i]);
        }
        printf(")");
    };
}

int main(){

    /* variable declaration */
    char str[SIZE];

    printf("Enter a zip code: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    check(str);

    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a simple C code that validates a 5 character zip code string from the user. If less than 5 characters, program outputs error message. If exactly 5 characters, places parenthesis around zip code.

When I test my code, only my error message works. My 'else if' parameter isn't being executed when I input 5 characters. Is it the way I'm passing the char input to my function?

Comment: it's working for me.. what's the problem?

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the `}` of the second `for` loop in `check()` is superfluous; it marks the end of an empty statement. (Also, `check()` is not a good name for a function; it should probably be `check_zip()` or something similar)

Comment: It is also a good idea to ensure that messages end with a newline so that the output appears in a timely manner.  When you're prompting before an input, the newline is not such a good idea, but using `fflush(stdout)` ensures that pending data is written.  It may appear anyway — quite often, the standard I/O library will flush pending output to standard output before reading data from standard input if both are connected to a terminal — but using the `fflush(stdout)` makes sure.

Comment: Grump: the erratic indentation before I edited the code means I misidentified the statement to which the `};` belongs — it's at the end of an `else if` statement, not the `for` loop, but it is still 100% superfluous (though mostly harmless in this context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I test my code, only my error message works. My 'else if' parameter isn't being executed when I input 5 characters. Is it the way I'm passing the char input to my function?

No. It's because you are using buffered output. `printf` stores its output in an internal buffer until either the buffer is full or it has to print a new line `\n`. Your program is exiting before `printf` has a chance to flush the buffer to the output. You need to terminate your final `printf` with a `\n`.

```
printf(")\n");
```

You do want a new line there, anyway, otherwise, if it did print, the next shell prompt will be on the same line.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the tip and explanation!!! The code I posted was actually a simplified project of something else I was working on. I did as you suggested and it worked.

Comment: @JPham Glad it helped. If this was the right answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your input contains characters and characters are not taken care in your code.

```
1234a
output: Enter a zip code: Not enough digits on input!

12345
output:Program Output: (12345)
```

Take a look at your for loop inside **check** function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that You may not be passing the 5 numbers, do the following, add antes else to debug
else`printf ("%s  %d", tel, strlen (tel));`

Answer (score 0):

[image: It is working fine] So please try to use GCC compiler if not ! The other case of error will be wrong input! Program is working fine according to your expectation ! [image]